# Getting vlc SAP Broadcast dump

Tags: vlc, dump

I am receiving SAP broadcasts, which I can normally use and play using the standalone vlc application.

I have been asked to provide a dump of the same. I have 2 questions:

1. I dont clearly understand what exactly dump is
2. How can I obtain the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of dumps, so you might first find out, what kind of dump is meant. It could be a database dump, which is similar to a backup, but usually it's a memory dump.

A *memory dump* or *crash dump* is a copy of the application including its memory at a specific point in time. Usually you want to create a dump exactly at the time an application is crashing or hanging. The dump will then be helpful to find the cause of the problem.

There are many ways to obtain a dump. First, Windows might do that for you, when it asks "Send information to Microsoft". Second, you can create it using Task Manager. Right click a process and choose "Create dump file". Third, there are many tools out there, e.g. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx), which all have pros and cons and serve different purposes.

To suggest a tool for your specific case, we would need more information. Exact wording might matter in this situation.

**Update**

In your particular case it looks like SAP means Service Advertising Protocol, which is related to the network. A broadcast is a message which is sent to everybody.

You could capture that one with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), but you would need a lot of network knowledge to get the filters set up. In this case the term "dump" probably refers to a something similar to a database dump, because SAP uses tables to store lists of services.